# What is the equivalent of Tornado Cash on Ethereum in Solana for making private transactions?

Tags: transactions

Is there a tornadao cash type application on Solana for creating private transactions? And is there a risk of a ban on this service and how would it get banned?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it constitutes a "status update"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, yes, there is [Otter Cash](https://otter.cash/).

Secondly, no one knows what is going to happen in the future.

[Here](https://twitter.com/NeerajKA/status/1556829480622215175?s=20&t=xe2K4zYVvTs564jglXpfNg) is something which might clear some doubts you have.